# Spring integration - how to split list of object to individual spring integration message using splitter

Tags: spring-integration

We are using splitter aggregator design pattern and we have one custom object say for eg List of product. Now we want each product to be sent as a message to channel for further processing.

How can we achieve that using spring integration?

Comment: Sorry, you have to share more information, maybe some solution, config. Looks like you have an answer in the question already. `Splitter` is there exactly for the task to emit each `List` item as a message downstream.

Comment: Sorry Artem, I should have wait little longer and should have debug my code before I post this question. Using splitter has fixed the issue.

Comment: Great! Please, remove then the question here as a noise. And vote to some my answers since I spend some time with you anyway ;-)

Comment: I have same problem and don't understand yet. I get a list from a rest api and use http-gateway for it and put result into channel. I want now a splitter between what get the list from input-channel and puts the elements each by each into the output channel. I guess the problem very similar here. An Example would be awesome :-)